# ASP.NET Core Web API Authentication with ASP.NET Identity login page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We are building An ASP.NET Core application which has already got login page there. This login page is developed with ASP.NET Identity and ASP.NET Core Views. Once you log in there will be a landing page(Dashboard) which also loaded first time with post back.

Now when the user interacts with a page like clicking on the chart to view details we want to make an Ajax call to ASP.NET Core Web API which we have already developed.

Here we want to make sure that API must be secured and can be only accessed with proper rights i.e. Person should be logged into the system.

So is this flow is supported with ASP.NET Identity? As I am logged with Normal Web Page and not using JWT tokens to secure Web APIS.

If there is any example that would be a real help.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a complete answer but i suggest you to have a look at OWIN middleware http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Comment: Sure I will look into it

Comment: Is `ASP.NET Core Web API` a different application you want to make AJAX call to? So you have one ASP.NET Core application for login and dashboard and another one for hosting API. Is that correct?

Comment: Not its, not a different application. ASP.NET Core application contains views and API both. So you have controller for views and API controllers for API